# How to jump over stuff in Inform 7

Tags: inform7

I have a "door" (a turnstile) between two rooms in Inform 7, and I want the player to have to jump over it.

I have:

```
The turnstile is inside of the Library. The turnstile is a door. 
The turnstile is locked and closed and openable.
The turnstile can be jumped over.

Instead of jumping turnstile:
    say "You jumped over the turnstile and ran into the library";
    now the player is in Collab Room;
```

but I get the error:

> Problem. You wrote 'Instead of jumping turnstile'  , which seems to introduce a rule taking effect only if the action is 'jumping turnstile'. But that did not make sense as a description of an action. I am unable to place this rule into any rulebook.
>    See the manual: 7.1 > 7.1. Actions

I checked out that section, and googled a bunch, no luck. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The jumping action in the Standard Rules doesn't accept a noun. You'll have to define a new action.

```
Jumping over is an action applying to one thing.
Understand "jump [something]" and "jump over [something]" as jumping over.

Check jumping over:
    say "That seemed unnecessary." instead.

Instead of jumping over the turnstile:
    say "You jumped over the turnstile and ran into the library.";
    now the player is in Collab Room;
```

As a side note, `The turnstile can be jumped over` doesn't do anything by itself: it can be used as a part of the logic for custom rules but Inform doesn't actually understand English so it doesn't automatically pick up such instructions.

Comment: That works and makes sense, thanks! You really can do anything with inform7 I'm learning.